# Получаю ошибку - 500 RestApi

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Доброго времени суток хочу получить список людей по имени, но к сожалению получаю ошибку сервера. В чем может быть моя ошибка.

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {


    List<Person> getAllByName(String name);

}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PersonService(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }


    public Person findOne(int id) {
        Optional<Person> foundPerson = personRepository.findById(id);
        return foundPerson.orElseThrow(PersonNotFoundException::new);
    }


    public List<Person> getPersonByName(String name) {
        return personRepository.getAllByName(name);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PeopleController {

    private final PersonService personService;
    @Autowired
    public PeopleController(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }


    @GetMapping
    public List<Person> getPeople() {
        return personService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Person getPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    return personService.findOne(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    List<Person> getAllByName(@PathVariable String name) {
        return personService.getPersonByName(name);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    private ResponseEntity<PersonErrorResponse> handleException(PersonNotFoundException exception) {
        PersonErrorResponse personErrorResponse = new PersonErrorResponse(
                "Person with id wasn't found", LocalDate.now()
        );

        return new ResponseEntity<>(personErrorResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавляйте стектрейсы, пожалуйста, текстом, а не скриншотом. Так будет легче вам помочь.

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке же все написано. У вас два метода, привязаны к пути `/people/{something}`.
Если вы запросите, скажем, `/people/42`, контроллер не сможет понять, строку `"42"` вы имели в виду или число `42`.

Так что для запроса списка пользователей по имени, замапьте метод `getAllByName`  на отдельный путь типа `/people/by-name/{name}`

Comment: получается, спасибо. ну я перевел, как неоднозначность метода.